# A property of infimum??

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be some space (eg. vector space or Banach space).

When is it true that: for any $\epsilon >0$ small, there exists an $f \in X$ such that
$$(1+\epsilon) \inf_{g \in X} I(g) \geq I(f)?$$
Here $I:X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true whenever $$\inf_{g \in X}I(g) > 0 \ \ \ \mbox{ or } \ \ \ \min_{g \in X}I(g) = 0$$
to see this, simply apply the definition of $\inf$.

On the contrary, if $\inf_{g \in X}I(g) < 0$, you cannot find such an $f$ because otherwise
$$I(f) \le (1+ \epsilon) \inf_{g \in X}I(g) < \inf_{g \in X}I(g) \le I(f)$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. So $f$ depends on $\epsilon$. Can we say that $f(\epsilon) \to \text{arginf}_g I(g)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, or something similar?

Comment: well, arginf doesn't exist necessarily, so maybe something similar holds?

Comment: You need some hypothesis on $I$ (e.g. continuity) to say something like this. But I am not so sure. Actually I am not familiar with arginf at all.